# ROS Answers SE migration: gazebo msgs

Tags: joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to publish a gazebo_msgs ( topic) NOT service using .cpp code as a node
I wrote the code, but I dont know what to add in the Cmakelist in these sections:

```
  find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  nav_msgs
  roscpp 
   ...../// what should I write here 
 }
```

// second

```
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES rosaria_nav
 CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime nav_msgs roscpp sensor_msgs ***gazebo_msgs***
 // is it right ????? 
 #  DEPENDS system_lib
)
```

// third

```
generate_messages(
 DEPENDENCIES
 geometry_msgs  sensor_msgs nav_msgs visualization_msgs gazebo_msgs
)
```

// forth

I added the following

```
add_executable(SetModelState src/SetModelState.cpp)
add_dependencies(SetModelState ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg ${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_messages_cpp)  
target_link_libraries(SetModelState
 ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)
```

//fifth
in the .cpp file ( the node ), I added the following library

```
 #include <gazebo_msgs/SetModelState.h>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155316/gazebo-msgs/) by [RSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/13151/rsa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2014-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the first section, you definitely need to add the "gazebo_msgs" package to the list of packages to find with "find_package" -- otherwise you won't be able to find the SetModelState.h

Adding "gazebo_msgs" to the CATKIN_DEPENDS in #2 is ok, but possibly not required. (technically this would be required if you had header files that referenced gazebo_msgs header files, and thus a package depending on yours would need to know about gazebo_msgs -- even if you aren't doing this, adding it to the CATKIN_DEPENDS really won't hurt anybody)

The third block is only required if you are actually creating new messages in this package -- are you? Even then, to actually required gazebo_msgs, you would have to have defined your own message that uses a gazebo_msgs message within it.

The fourth block seems fine -- again though, if you don't have custom messages, you won't need the "add_dependency" line.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0